# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace in apache flink 1.10 deploy kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I am using apache flink 1.10 to consume RabbitMQ message and sink to MySQL using restful api, now the taskmanager exit and throw error:

```
2020-07-02 05:36:01,464 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks (1/1) (c5607a434c6da19872cf5e0a8dda761a) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
2020-07-02 05:36:02,369 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Window(TumblingEventTimeWindows(5000), EventTimeTrigger, SumField, CollectionWindow) -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) (6dfa060a1e92735ba60e28c7e5871a56) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1925)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2099)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
```

and this is my part of Apache Flink jobs code:

```
public static void pumpConsumeHandler() throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        FlinkUtil.initEnv(env);
        RMQSource dataSource = FlinkUtil.initDatasource("goblin.pump.report.realtime");
        DataStream<String> dataStreamSource = env.addSource(dataSource);
        DataStream<ReportPump> record =
                dataStreamSource.map(new MapFunction<String, ReportPump>() {
                    @Override
                    public ReportPump map(String value) throws Exception {
                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        ReportPump pumpRecord = mapper.readValue(value, ReportPump.class);
                        return pumpRecord;
                    }
                }).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new CustomAssign<ReportPump>());

        record.keyBy(new KeySelector<ReportPump, Tuple2<Integer, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Integer, Long> getKey(ReportPump value) throws Exception {
                return Tuple2.of(value.getGameType(), value.getTenantId());
            }
        })
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .reduce(new SumField(), new CollectionWindow())
                .addSink(new SinkFunction<List<ReportPump>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(List<ReportPump> reportPumps, Context context) throws Exception {
                        persistCollectData(reportPumps);
                    }
                });
        env.execute(PumpRealtimeHandler.class.getName());
    }

    public static void persistCollectData(List<ReportPump> records) throws Exception {
        PumpConsumeService service = FlinkUtil.InitRetrofit().create(PumpConsumeService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.savePumpRecords(records);
        ResponseBody body = call.execute().body();
        String str = new String(body.bytes(), "UTF-8");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response response = mapper.readValue(str, Response.class);
        if (!ServiceException.API_OK.equals(response.getResultCode())) {
            log.error("save error:" + str);
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            log.debug("success：" + str);
        }
    }
```

to solve this problem, I tweak the config:

```
taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 256mb(from default 96M to 256M)
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2g(from 1G to 2G)
```

I have 2 flink jobs, what should I do to avoid this problem? how much metaspace size should I config?

Comment: the double size of metadata space?

Comment: Tweak size to 512?@Felipe

Comment: yes. just change and re-execute to see what happens. This size refers to the actual state that you are processing. If you know beforehand what is your workload you can calculate. But you are using `StreamExecutionEnvironment` and the workload can fluctuate at any time. But considering that you know the domain that you are working on, you can estipulate a good value for multiple jobs running.

Comment: @Felipe I have this problem also, doubling the metaspace doesn't help. Maybe I just need more taskmanagers? In my case the job is reading 14.4GB gzipped csvs into a DataSet on two taskmanagers that have been assigned 25GB memory each.